Geometric interpretation and upper bounds on Euclidean distance in Lie algebra of SO(3)
$\newcommand{\Log}{\operatorname{Log}}
\newcommand{\Exp}{\operatorname{Exp}}$
Let $\Exp : \mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto SO(3)$ denote the composition of the standard $SO(3)$ exponential map with the natural isomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathfrak{so}(3)$, and $\Log$ its inverse in the neighborhood of $I$.
Let $R$ and $R'$ be two rotations in $SO(3)$. For purposes of an application, I am interested in bounding the quantity
$$
\newcommand{\Log}{\operatorname{Log}}
d_1(R, R') := \lVert \Log R - \Log R' \rVert_2
$$
in terms of the quantity
$$
d_2(R, R') := \lVert \Log (R^\top R') \rVert_2,
$$
that is, the angle of the shortest rotation from $R$ to $R'$.
Clearly no useful bound exists for arbitrary $R, R'$ - take, for example
$R = \Exp([\pi - \epsilon, 0, 0])$ and $R' = \Exp([-\pi + \epsilon, 0, 0])$ for small $\epsilon > 0$.
These two rotations have $d_1(R, R') \approx 2\pi$ but $d_2(R, R') \approx 2 \epsilon$ for $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small.
However, suppose we add the assumption that $d_2(R, I) \leq \pi/2$ and $d_2(R', I) \leq \pi/2$ - that is, that both $R$ and $R'$ are no more than $\pi/2$ radians from the identity. Then it seems some useful bound should be possible.
Empirically, we can sample random rotations satisfying this constraint and compare $d_1$ to $d_2$.
Here is a plot, with samples biased towards small rotations, where "metric" means $d_1$ and "angle" means $d_2$.
In this sample, $d_1 > d_2$ always, and $d_1 \leq  2 d_2$ appears to be a loose bound.

However, I as far as I can tell, the construct $d_1(\cdot, \cdot)$ is not geometrically meaningful and has not been discussed in the literature. I am a novice with Lie theory so I am struggling to prove a bound myself. Any insight into the geometric intuition would also be potentially useful!

One can prove that $d_1\le \frac{\pi}{2} d_2$ in this setting. One can get sharper bounds depending on the distance to the identity. Not sure what kind of bounds you are looking for. This can be treated either as a differential geometry problem (estimating magnitudes of Jacobi fields on the sphere which are well-known) or spherical trigonometry problem.

@MoisheKohan the $d_1 \leq \frac{\pi}{2} d_2$ is what I am looking for! Αny references would be appreciated. Thanks for your comment!

I do not have a reference, but I will write an answer when I have time. Do you know any Riemannian geometry, especially, Jacobi fields?

The 2-norm on the Lie algebra of $SO(3)$ (the space of skew-symmetric $3\times 3$ matrices) is, up to a constant multiple, the Frobenius norm, i.e. with this norm $SO(3)$ is a Riemannian manifold. I assume at this point that you know some basic Riemannian geometry (say, chapters 0-5 of do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry").   The above Riemannian metric on $SO(3)$ is bi-invariant, hence, lifts to a bi-invariant Riemannian metric on $SU(2)$ (which is diffeomorphic to $S^3$), hence, up to a constant multiple, this is the standard Riemannian metric on the unit sphere $S^3\subset \mathbb R^4$.  The constant rescaling of the norm does not change anything, hence, I will assume that we are dealing with the standard Riemannian metric on $S^3$. The subset of rotations by the angle $\le \pi/2$ then corresponds to the closed metric ball $B\subset SU(2)$ centered at $1\in SU(2)$ and of the (Riemannian) radius $\pi/4$. The matrix exponential map is the same as the Riemannian exponential map (this is true for all compact connected Lie groups equipped with bi-invariant Riemannian metrics). Thus, your problem becomes of bounding from above the Lipschitz constant of the map $\log_1: B\to T_1(SU(2))$, the latter is the tangent space at $1$ to $SU(2)=S^3$. (Here $\log_1$ is the inverse to the Riemannian exponential map $\exp_1$.) The Riemannian exponential map is an isometry along radial Euclidean geodesics and preserves angles between these geodesics and tangent vectors to $S^3$ (this is a general property of Riemannian exponential maps). The derivative of the Riemannian exponential map is described by Jacobi fields on the Riemannian manifold (see Chapter 5 in do Carmo). Suppose that $M$ is a complete Riemannian manifold, $c: [0, T]\to M$ is a  geodesic, $c(0)=p$, $c'(0)=u$. Consider a vector $tv$ in $A=T_pM$ orthogonal to $u$; take its translate $w$ (with the tail at $tu$),  which we regard as a vector in $T_{tu}A$ (here we treat $A$ as an affine space).
The goal is to compute $(d\exp_p)_{tu}(w)\in T_{c(t)}M$ (the image of $w$ under the derivative of $\exp_p$).  To do so, take the unique Jacobi field $J(t)\in T_{c(t)}M$ along the geodesic $c$, satisfying $J(0)=0$, $J'(0)=v$. Then
$$
J(t)= (d\exp_p)_{tu}(w). 
$$
This vector is orthogonal to the geodesic $c$. Reversing the exponential map, we get
$$
\log_p (J(t))= w,
$$
and $w$ is a translate of the vector $tv$. In particular,
$$
|(d\log_p)_{c(t)}(J(t))|=|tv|= t|v|. 
$$
Consider now the case when $M$ is the unit sphere and $c$ is a unit speed geodesic ($|u|=1$) and $|v|=1$. Then the norm of Jacobi field $J$ is given by
$$
|J(t)|= |\sin(t)|. 
$$
Thus, the derivative of $\log_p$ at $c(t)$ sends tangent vectors $\nu$ orthogonal to $c'(t)$ to vectors orthogonal to the ray $\mathbb R_+ u$ and with the norm
$$
\frac{t}{|\sin(t)|} |\nu|.
$$
At the same time $d\log_p$ preserves lengths of vectors tangent to the geodesic $c$. Hence, the norm of $d\log_p$ at $c(t)$ equals
$$
\frac{t}{|\sin(t)|}. 
$$
Lastly, we restrict to $t\in (0, \frac{\pi}{4})$ and obtain the upper bound
$$
\frac{\pi/4}{\sin(\pi/4)}= \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}
$$
on the Lipschitz constant of $\log_1$ on the ball $B$. One can obtain the same bound by elementary geometry means by comparing lengths of circles on the unit sphere and in the Euclidean plane. To conclude: You have the inequality
$$
d_1\le \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}} d_2
$$
assuming that the angle of rotation is $\le \pi/2$.

Thank you very much for this detailed answer! I will need to learn much background material, so thanks also for the book suggestion.
